# Android Tab changers to tab3 but the content appears the same as tab1

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to load the tab3 on the load but it loads tab3 with the content of tab1. the following is the code i make for the 3 tabs to load and i want the tab3 to be loaded on 1st.

```
package sh.mkt;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class thirdtab extends TabActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid2");
TabSpec thiredTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid3");

firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Buying Cost").setContent(new Intent(this,tab1.class));
secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Selling Cost").setContent(new Intent(this,tab2.class));
thiredTabSpec.setIndicator("Portfolio").setContent(new Intent(this,tab3.class));

tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
tabHost.addTab(thiredTabSpec);
tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(2);
}
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">  
        <LinearLayout  
            android:orientation="vertical"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
            android:padding="5dp">  
            <TabWidget  
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"  
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:gravity="center" 
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>  
            <FrameLayout  
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"  
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
                android:padding="5dp"/>  
        </LinearLayout>  
    </TabHost>
```

Comment: changed the problem is still the same

Comment: TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid2");
TabSpec thiredTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid3");

this is what your talking right?

Comment: yes but you can still take tid1 in all ..just go through the link buddy they have given a working example...i think you might have mistaken in all your 3 diff java classes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all three you have set "tid1" problem might be there....
You may refer to [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1)...

> for trial reason if you have kept all class same than take a look at their XML you might have forgot  change its setcontentview().

PERFECT SOLUTION:

JUST USE:

**tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);**

instead of yours(tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(2);)

cheeers!!!!!

Comment: i changed that also to tid1,tid2,tid3 but still its the same. it loads the tab3 but shows the content of tab1

Answer (score 1):

you might be making a demo like [this example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1) then i doubt that you have written 3 different java file to show on each tab. Please go throught the link once.